# Why is it bad practice to do sql and most logic directly in a Web API controller communicating with a SPA

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am struggling to understand why abstraction is necessary for asp.net core web api. I am a very amateur programmer so this may be a terrible question but I am struggling to find a good answer regarding this. My application is an MVC application but it is a SPA so I have decided to finally separate my backend and my frontend. But this is why I am starting to question my current backend setup. I currently have a controller for each aspect of my application such as a DashboardController, AccountController , etc for each page of my application so I consolidate my api request to its respective page/controller. I do take advantage of some dependency injection and services for things that I use across controllers and methods in controllers such as ms graph methods to download documents, or send emails, etc. Anytime I run a dapper sql query I do it directly in the controller as this example:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetMyReviews()
    {

        string json;
        string query;

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {

            query = "select dbo.storedprocedure_JSON(@UserID)";

            json = await connection.QuerySingleAsync<string>(query, new { UserID = UserID });

        }

        if (json == null)
        {
            json = "[]";
        }

        return Content(json, "application/json");
    }
```

I have a million of these types of queries in my controllers to pull data from our database and pass to the frontend and sometimes I will do additional stuff with the data before updating the db or before sending back to the frontend. From this article of implementing dapper:

https://code-maze.com/using-dapper-with-asp-net-core-web-api/

The author creates a dbcontext service as a transient which is then injected into another repository/interface which is where the database calls are made. The repository/interface itself is then called from the controllers. This creates 3 separate areas that code needs to be maintained vs mind where I am just putting everything in the controller for the most part. Also, when you see implmenting the dbcontext directly into the service even still requires as much code with the using statement compared to mine so again it seems to not make much sense to me:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Company>> GetCompanies()
{
    var query = "SELECT * FROM Companies";
    using (var connection = _context.CreateConnection())
    {
        var companies = await connection.QueryAsync<Company>(query);
        return companies.ToList();
    }
}
```

So is my way the incorrect way of doing this and I should follow this author (many articles I read follow this similar approach) or is simple best? I have about 15 controllers using my approach. Is this authors approach only worth separating things out or abstracting if you are planning to reuse functionality over and over and over?

Comment: I also have a lot of questions like this at times. One thing I've find out that could help you is that most of these good practices described by authors and tutors are based on a generic point of view, following common sense design patterns and mostly what makes sense for the coorp industry. I'm not saying that applies for your question, but there is many things we've been taught that are overengineering or just don't apply for our specific custom implementations.